# Can I use "top" without "of" when talking about something at a high position?

Tags: grammar

For example say when I see a sign at a high position when I am on the road can I say "Can you see the sign on the top"? Or do I have to say "Can you see the sign on the top of blah blah?" If I can't use "top" by itself, what word or words should I use in this situation?

Comment: "Can you see that sign up there?"

Comment: Sure, you can use ***top*** without explicitly specifying ***of** [something]*.  Come to that, you can quite naturally say [I'm going up top](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m+going+up+top%22) without the definite article, though some might say that's primarily only a colloquial / spoken usage.

Comment: *Look at that mountain. Can you see the sign at the top?* - fine usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Max, you think that my sentence is wrong? Also Davo, should I say "at the top" instead of "on the top" in this situation?

Comment: "On top", "on top of", or "at the top" all work. Note "at the" but no "the" with "on".

Answer (score 0):

Look at that mountain. Can you see the sign at the top? - fine usage. – [Davo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/48224/davo)

Sure, you can use top without explicitly specifying of [something]. Come to that, you can quite naturally say [I'm going up top](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m%20going%20up%20top%22) without the definite article, though some might say that's primarily only a colloquial / spoken usage. – [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers)

Whether you use "at the top" or "on the top" depends on context and meaning (the difference in meaning between at and on), though the difference is slight and in many cases both are fine. When the context allows "of the hill" to be understood you could say: "I'll meet you at the top"(point location) and "There is a house on the top" (positioned above).